# Unknown override specifer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a game using C++ and SDL (I'm still new and learning).

I've been stuck on this for some time, and I'm not sure how to solve this.

This is `Game.h` where I'm trying to create the actual game:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Input.h"

struct Objects
{
    GameObject player;
    Input input;
};

class Game
{
public:
    Game() {};
    ~Game() {};

    void init(int width, int height, bool fullscreen);
    void handleEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    void clean();

    bool inline running() 
    { 
        return _isRunning; 
    }

    static SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    static SDL_Event event;
    
private:    
    bool _isRunning = true;
    SDL_Window* _window = nullptr;  
    SDL_Texture* texture = nullptr; 

    GameObjectsRef data = std::make_shared<Objects>();
};
```

And this is `GameObjects.h` where I'm doing things related to objects of the game:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "TextureManager.h"

class GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject() {};
    ~GameObject() {};

    void init();
    void render();
    void update();

    int xpos = 0;
    int ypos = 0;
    int dx = 0;
    int dy = 0;

    private:    
        SDL_Texture* texture = nullptr;
        //GameObjectsRef data;
    };
```

I found some answers where it says there might be issues with multiple includes, but shouldnt `#pragma once` take care of that?

Error messages in the `Game.h` lines 12 and 13

```
Error   C3646   'player': unknown override specifier
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support 
Error   C3646   'input': unknown override specifier 
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: @bboyMinato That's wrong in many ways. Must importantly you put `inline` in the wrong place `inline bool` not `bool inline`. Secondly functions defined inside classes are automatically inline, so inline is not needed in this situation. And finally `inline` in C++ has nothing to do with speed, and everything to do with where you define functions.

Comment: @PeteBecker- it only shows this problem when i include objects in the struct when i delete that everything works perfectly

Comment: Show the `#include` lines in `"TextureManager.h"`

Comment: `#include "Game.h"
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>` @BenVoigt

Comment: I'm guessing some problem in `"Input.h"`

Comment: @john thanks ill keep that in mind for the inline

Comment: There's your problem, TextureManager.h -> Game.h -> GameObject.h -> TextureManager.h infinite cycle

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "Game.h"` these are include is `input.h"

Comment: @bboyMinato OK, but Ben has found the problem. Cyclic dependency of header files.

Comment: @bboyMinato: That's also wrong, Game.h -> Input.h -> Game.h another infinite cycle.

Comment: @BenVoigt what would be the best way to write it without having infinte cycle

Comment: Take `#include "Game.h"` out of both `TextureManager.h` and `Input.h`   Maybe add a forward declaration `class Game;` in its place

Comment: @BenVoigt im using a `static renderer` from `Game.h` so im able to draw on screen and use it to create textures and other things...

Comment: @bboyMinato It's hard to say without seeing the exact details of your classes, but never have cyclic includes, Use forward declarations to break any cycles.

Comment: @john okay i dont know rly much about forward declarations so ill try to learn about that before doing anything else

Comment: Maybe you need to move that `static SDL_Renderer* renderer;` to a different class that `Game` and `TextureManager` can both depend on, without depending on each other.

Comment: @bboyMinato But do you have to use it in the header file. Move that use to a cpp file.

Comment: @john im not rly familiar with the OOP and how to properly write a code and thats what im struggling the most rn

Comment: @bboyMinato designing games is a fairly advanced topic. If you don't even understand the basics of OOP yet, you are going to have a hard time.